# Creating and assigning a new NSManagedObject to a new NSManagedObject *sometimes* fails

Tags: swift, core-data, exc-bad-access

I am creating a new NSManagedObject called "translation". Within the translation I need to create two additional NSManagedObjects called "phrase". Sometimes one of the phrase assignments will throw an error, but when I inspect the values they all look like they were created just fine. What gives???

[image: error when adding a phrase to a translation]

[image: threads]

**Creating A Translation Object:**

```
func getOrCreateTranslation(package: Package?, data: NSDictionary) -> Translation {
        let translationId = data["id"] as! NSNumber

        if let translation = self.getTranslation(translationId) {

            return translation

        } else {

            let context = LocalDataStorage().context
            let translation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Translation", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Translation
            translation.id = translationId

            let fromPhrase = data["from_phrase"]! as! NSDictionary
            let toPhrase = data["to_phrase"]! as! NSDictionary


            let pm = PhraseManager()

            //*******
            // *SOMETIMES* ONE OF THESE LINES FAIL WITH BAD_EXC_ACCESS code=1
            translation.fromPhrase = pm.getOrCreatePhrase(fromPhrase)
            translation.toPhrase = pm.getOrCreatePhrase(toPhrase)
            //******

            if package != nil {
                package!.addTranslationObject(translation)
            }

            return translation

        }

    }
```

**Creating A Phrase Object:**

```
func getOrCreatePhrase(data: NSDictionary) -> Phrase {
        // check if phrase exists
        let phraseId = data["id"] as! NSNumber

        if let phrase = self.getPhrase(phraseId) {

            return phrase

        } else {

            let context = localDataStorage.context
            let lm = LanguageManager()
            let phrase = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Phrase", inManagedObjectContext: context) as! Phrase

            phrase.id = phraseId
            phrase.text = data["text"] as! String
            phrase.audioUrl = data["audio_url"] as? String

            let code = data["language"]!["language_code"] as! String
            phrase.language = lm.getLanguageFromCode(code)

            return phrase

        }



    }
```

**Call Made to API:**

```
func getPackageTranslations(package: Package, completion: ([Translation])-> Void) {

    let currentLanguage: Language = LanguageManager().getCurrentLanguage()!

    let urlString = baseAPIString + "/groups/\(package.id!)/translations/?language_code=\(currentLanguage.code)"


    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let serachUrl = NSURL(string: urlString)


    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(serachUrl!) {
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {



            let jsonData: NSDictionary!
            do {
                jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
            } catch _ {
                jsonData = NSDictionary()
            }

            let groupTranslationsData = jsonData["group_translations"] as! [NSDictionary]



            var translations = [Translation]()
            let context = LocalDataStorage().context

            for groupTranslation in groupTranslationsData {

                let translationData = groupTranslation["translation"] as! NSDictionary

                let translation = TranslationManager().getOrCreateTranslation(package, data: translationData)


                if translation.packages?.containsObject(package) == false {
                    //package.addTranslationObject(translation!)
                    //translation!.addPackageObject(package)
                }

                translations.append(translation)

            }


            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                print("There was a problem saving translation ")
            }




            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                completion(translations)
            })


        }

    }
    task.resume()

}
```

**CoreData Context Class:**

```
    class LocalDataStorage {
    let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context: NSManagedObjectContext!

    init() {
        context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    }

}
```

Comment: What thread are you running on and how is the context configured?

Comment: Agree. Highly likely to be cause by this code running on a different thread to which the managedObjectContext was created on. When you do this, it sometimes works and sometimes fails.

Comment: Thank you both for the replies. @Wain, I added two more functions involved, and a pic of the running threads, to the description above. I *do* make a call to an API, but the objects and context.save happen before the dispatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs when you create a NSManagedObjectContext with a concurrency pattern that it should be interacted on and you perform actions on the it on a thread different from the concurrency pattern specified during its initialization.

The completion block of NSURLSession.dataTaskWithURL is run on another thread, so you must dispatch to the type of thread specified in the context creation to perform any operation successfully on it.

If the concurrency type of your context is MainQueueConcurrencyType which is used in most cases, you must perform the context save method on the main queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
  do {
     try context.save()
  } catch {
     print("There was a problem saving translation ")
  }
  completion(translations)
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmed! Since the other steps before dispatch were synchronous I thought they would fully execute before the dispatch. After your tip I still had issues with other saves and ended up moving the entire JSON parsing and object creating to the dispatch block. Works like a charm now!